# What causes political apathy?

Tags: citizen-activism

A lot of people are averse to politics, specifically when there is minority representation in media or representation of issues relating to them. But isn't this impossible to avoid? Almost everything we do has *some* effect on others and at some point, if the effect is significant enough, the affected party would voice their frustration, especially if there is a solution. Are there any ways to reduce political apathy?

https://academic.oup.com/poq/article-abstract/18/4/349/1925107?redirectedFrom=fulltext

Comment: This may be of interest https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/american-political-science-review/article/abs/dimensions-of-political-alienation/101DAB41ECAC17991029A27B79CDF6EB  DIscussed on Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Political_alienation

Comment: Please cite the sources for your claims.

Comment: Could you define your terms better?  Do you mean "minority" as "political party no in the majority" or "protected class of people"?   Also, what does the definition of political apathy mean?  Is it voting for the same party you always do because "better [party color] than [a rhyming alternative]?  Or is it no-voting or non-interest in activist issues.

Comment: minority includes both in my definition.

Comment: Typically, the apathy arises because *the effect is not significant* - either because it is inherently small or because one cannot influence the system. In the latter case apathy can be also a form of political protest. Finally, there is also philosophical view that one's ignorance about the potential consequences of voting creates the risk of doing more harm than good, hence abstention is the most moral choice.

Comment: Politics.

*ba dum tss*

Comment: Take the Netherlands: people feel that the government completely ignores them, that even the way people vote has no influence on the direction the government takes. As a result people often don't bother to vote, they stay at home. Having a PM who's had 4 votes of no confidence already but is still in power after over a decade is a clear sign that the people are right btw.

Comment: "political apathy" seems to be a very broad term. It could mean not running for office, not voting, not contributing to campaigns, avoiding political discussions with friends, or simply not having a strong opinion in those discussions. Analyzing all of these could fill a book.

Answer (score 7):

Answering this question might require some "anecdotal vibe check" but I'll give it a try.

Generally, political apathy arises when a person believes they have no way to meaningfully influence the political outcome of their society.

Contrary to popular belief, these people are not disinterested in politics, but rather they care so much about politics that they fear being disappointed by the structure they find themselves in, so the solution is to just mentally check out.

What created this?

- **Authoritarian system**: Plain and simple, you have no chance of influencing politics if you live in this structure. Cynicism is the natural response.
- **Poorly designed political system**: Some countries are prone to political deadlock, such as the United States and Italy. In these places, people are used to their popular will not being expressed clearly through the system, this makes it easier to generate apathy or populism.
- **Corruption**: If there is no firewall between politicians and private monies, the private sector could quickly hijack the public sector, which inhibits the expression of popular will. This is most famously demonstrated in the [Citizens United](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Citizens_United_v._FEC) case which removed virtually all restrictions on dark money in American elections, the result is citizens will always be outspent by corporations or oligarchs.
- **[Voter suppression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voter_suppression)**: Some regions systematically exlcude voters from the electoral process. This could create generational learned-helplessness where people within family or community convince each other not to even try participating in politics.

Notice that I mostly cite structural reasons to political apathy, which implies they are not the fault of the voters, but rather the system they find themselves in. If you fix the structural issue, then voters will naturally make their voice heard - at least that is what I believe.

Comment: @user253751 Bad spellers of the world, untie!

Comment: @user253751 Corrected. Stack Exchange doesn't have built-in spellchecker.

Answer (score 7):

There's really two groups there

### Apolitical

These are your true people who don't care anything about politics. They are unlikely to care about political arguments and actively avoid political disagreements. This can sometimes be a willful choice (i.e. "I don't like political arguments"). This also encompasses the politically ignorant. Government just sort of... happens for them. As long as that world doesn't directly intersect their own, they remain blissfully unaware of what happens and they may or may not vote.

### The Political Cynic

This is a more pernicious (and likely larger) group. They know about politics, but what's the point of engagement? The politicians are going to do what they want anyways. That was a key in [low voter turnout for a 2017 referendum on Puerto Rico becoming a state](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2017_Puerto_Rican_status_referendum). 97% voted for statehood... but that represented a dismal 23% of all eligible voters. There were some arguments against the assertions of the referendum (namely that any option put them squarely under the thumb of the US government), but it's hard not to argue that those positions could be viewed as cynical. The pro-statehood forces got their political talking point and that's what they viewed was the purpose of the vote.

### Increasing engagement

Oddly enough, the COVID-19 pandemic response by governments gives us a pretty good answer: have more government intersectionality with the governed. In the US, for instance, [there was a sizeable turnout increase in 2020 vs 2016](https://www.census.gov/newsroom/press-releases/2022/2020-presidential-election-voting-report.html)

> More voters (154.6 million) turned out for the presidential election in 2020 than in 2016 (137.5 million), the largest increase between consecutive presidential elections since the inception of the CPS voting supplement in 1964.

It's hard to say that COVID policy was the only driver, (the death of George Floyd would be another driver there), but it helped fuel political engagement on both sides of the aisle (directly, through COVID policy, or indirectly through increased social media consumption).

Comment: Comments deleted. This is not the place to debate COVID-19 containment policies.

Answer (score 3):

I would argue that modern states explicitly discourage political participation by unaligned ordinary citizens (so-called normies).

- Binding polls (such as Brexit) are very rare, expensive and use legacy tech (ballot boxes, etc).
- Voters are expected to all-in on a certain political candidate or party, by choosing from a very short list of unattractive or unfamiliar options, some of whom may be pure fraud (election spoiling and such). This happens on very slow cycle of 2-6 years. There often aren't a terrible many of votings and most of decisions are made by professional bureaucrats not vetted by voting.
- Consumer information hardware is not used for politics, but when it is, that is often designed to make people with fringe, radical opinions to dominate (leftist Twitter or far-right chans come to mind).
- The political process is designed to have high barrier to entry and benefit entrenched actors such as already-established political parties, with offline and opaque casting for participation in politics.

We have all of this internet-enabled hardware which we trust to keep our money, but for some reason there is very limited movement towards political use of these possibilities. There may be some slight exceptions such as internet-enabled Estonia, but no political marvels from there as well.

In the end, people are apathic because they don't see a meaningful way to influence politics on day to day basis, so their political habits don't form.

Comment: The Brexit referendum was not binding - but the political pressure associated with a non-binding referendum (especially one as contentious as that) makes it all but impossible for a government to ignore it. Also the use of ballot boxes - as opposed to voting machines or other technological solutions - has (it can be argued) many advantages over alternatives (and I say that as a technophile).

Comment: There are quite a few assertions and generalisations in this answer. Could you provide some sources to back them up? I agree with your last sentence, but I'm not convinced by some of your arguments, at least without evidence.

Comment: @SteveMelnikoff Using paper ledgers or cheques may also confer similar benefits over banking over smartphone, but the point is that banking has figured out how to make wires secure, whereas politics institutions have not figured out how to make paperless secure.

Comment: @alamar Computerized voting can be totally secure. The problem is how to prove that to the voters. It's easy with banking, because you don't see any extra charges on your bank statement (other than the ones the bank itself adds to steal your money from you).

Comment: Moving semiannual voting online will not give huge benefits by itself in presense of other listed factors.

Comment: @user253751 Easy with banking? Seriously. Equifax thanks you for your support.

Comment: This is an interesting point of view. However, there is also that opposite view that modern western states encourage voting by everyone (and sometimes even make it obligatory) to legitimatize the selection among what is otherwise a very limited set of options.

Comment: May I remind you of Switzerland? We hold about a dozen binding votes every year, select our representatives from a smattering of parties (in my electoral district alone, 34 different parties stood for election, 9 of which achieved representation), E-Voting is in trials and participating in popular initiatives and referenda is a simple as visiting a website, printing a form, signing, and sending it to the government. Also, new parties form (and old parties perish) with some frequency: at the national level alone, the last two decades saw a party split, a merge, and the emergence of a new party.

Comment: Most countries are not Switzerland and are not copying much from its political system despite its apparent success.

Comment: ... but Switzerland is a modern state, so you might want to say that "some modern states explicitly discourage" rather than "modern states explicitly discourage". Your answer isn't stating a universal truth, but sounds like it does.

Comment: @paulj If there's nothing on your bank statement that you didn't agree to, then your banking was secure - it's that simple. This works because you can just look at your statement. It's hard with voting, because we want you to be able to verify your own vote, but *not* let anyone else verify your vote, or let you show your vote to anyone else. Even systems like ThreeBallot are too complicated for most people, so we settle for doing it the simple way but with lots of eyeballs watching. Eyeballs can't watch electrons, therefore computers are out.

Answer (score 1):

[This source](https://stoplearn.com/reasons-for-political-apathy/) provides more or less the following reasons for the political apathy:

1. It is not safe otherwise, unless your position is very close to the official one.
2. The elected representatives ignore the own promises made during elections.
3. The voters suspect major electoral malpractices.

Comment: Those don't all seem like reasons and it is missing a lot of other possible reasons.

Comment: If you get jailed for saying that you think, you do not need very complex reasons to stay shut up.

Comment: That doesn't mean you have political apathy though and your answer is still missing a lot of possible causes for it. Something as simple as they just don't care about it and never have.